# How would you define infinity?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, infinity

Expand your thoughts upon this:

```
#define INFINITY ((1 << (8*sizeof (int) - 6)) - 4)
```

Is expanded?

Comment: In what context? Why do you need a value representing infinity? And why `((1 << (8*sizeof (int) - 6)) - 4)`? Why not use `float` or `double` since they can represent positive/negative infinity?

Comment: I would usually say something like "a loop that will eventually burn your processor"... So yeah, it depends on the context.

Comment: if (distances[i*MAX_ZONES+j]==INFINITY)

Comment: And in what context is a distance equal to infinity?

Comment: The IEEE 754 representation for 32-bit `float` "infinity" as an integer is `0x7F800000`, which that equation does not yield.

Comment: It yields `0x03FFFFFC`, so sign is `+`, exponent is `0x07`, and mantissa is `0x7FFFFC`, which is `0x1.FFFFF8 * 2 ^ -120` which Python tells me is `1.5046324103201211e-36`. Not a value of particular interest. (Ref: [IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).)

Answer (score 5):

Why not

```
numeric_limits<float>::infinity()
```

or

```
numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Use `numeric_limits`  from `<limits>` header file, as

```
numeric_limits<float>::infinity()
```

See this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/